# Как сделать такое выравнивание с Flex

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Добрый день! учусь использовать Flexbox, вот решил сделать такой макет, и не могу понять как выровнять элементы по-левой стороне.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Примерно такая структура:

```
<div>    //display: flex
    <ul>   //display: flex, justify-content: space-around, flex-wrap; wrap;
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Но *justify-content*, выравнивает как на 2й картинке, а мне хотелось бы, какн а 1й, это возможно? Cgfcb,Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле всё просто, можно создать дополнительные `<div>` внутри тэгов `<li>`. А самим тегам `<li>` задать размер в соответствующий количеству, блоков которые нужны в строке, в данном случае для 3 - это будет 33%.Ну и соответственно родительскому блоку `<ul>` нужно задать `justify-content: flex-start;` Реализация:

```css
li{
  width: 33%; 
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center:
}
li div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><div></div></li>
        <li><div></div></li>
        <li><div></div></li>
        <li><div></div></li>
        <li><div></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по этом же вопросу на [Toster](https://toster.ru/q/372825) вам надо было что бы 5тый блок тянулся в том случае если он последний и если их 6 то становились одинаковыми , ну вот совственно реализация

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
main {
  display: flex;
}
aside,
article {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
aside {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40%;
}
article {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 59%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  min-height: 300px;
  justify-content: initial;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  margin: 10px;
}
.item:nth-last-child(5n+1) {
  /*чётные*/
  width: 321px;
  order: 5;
}
.item:nth-child(5n+1) {
  /*чётные*/
  width: 150px;
  order: ;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <article>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </article>
  <aside></aside>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

Это [песочница](http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/yVgGWy) для эксперимента